# Expression for when an actor has become so associated with a role that it becomes difficult to 'unsee'?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

Think of Daniel Radcliffe. Is there an expression that describes his situation or state of him always being associated with Harry Potter by many people?

Comment: The phenomenon is certainly related to typecasting, but it is not the same. Bela Lugosi always being cast as the villain is typecasting, but his realization "I am Dracula" is what we are looking for. Another example would be Leonard Nemoy's autobiography title "I am not Spock" or the advertisements-come-internet-meme where "captain Kirk" praises computer hardware.

Comment: That's advertisements-**cum**-internet meme.  If you're going to be fancy and use a Latin term, might as well spell it correctly. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cum

Comment: A quick internet search of the phrase:  **typecasting is the process by which a particular actor becomes strongly identified with a specific character** may prove interesting ... 

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Father Luke - This should be an answer. It just needs a little more detail and pointers to actual quotes.

Comment: @oerkelens '... by many people'? Admittedly, OP's title is misleading.

Comment: @oerkelens Although *typecasting* is often understood to mean "casting to a particular type of role", it is in fact a typographical metaphor (just like *stereotype*) and is used, inside and outside The Profession, for any compulsion to play the same role over and over. James O'Neill was *typecast* as Monte Cristo, Jay Silverheels as Tonto, Raymond Burr as Perry Mason.

Comment: Sometimes they say the actor will be _forever known as Harry Potter_.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann -- poasted as an answer for you, as requested. And thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Typecasting** *and* **Type casting** are the processes by which a particular actor becomes strongly identified with a specific character.

A quick internet search for the words: 
**type casting** and **typecasting**

...will find substantiation. Specific links not attached due to link degeneration.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Rather than listing the search terms by which your particular search engine on this particular day on your particular computer with your particular browsing history happened to return results that your experience allowed you to interpret as useful, please actually post some relevant quotes (properly attributed, of course). Also, for the one link you did include, please summarize what it has to say and/or post a relevant quote, because link rot is a fact of life on the internet.

Comment: You'll notice no search engine was specified, @Marthaª, nor were specific results specifically linked.

Comment: Precisely the problem: just because *you* found something relevant, today, in your particular environment, doesn't mean that six months from now I won't put your search terms into my search engine and find precisely... nothing. Not to mention, even if I do get something, how do I (as someone who doesn't already know the answer) figure out whether the pages I found are truly relevant or utter balderdash?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typecasting_(acting) This is a general reference source which supports the above answer.  Not having one is a legitimate problem, and I apologize for being dismissive of it.

Comment: (This is related to, but not the same issue as, [Google is not General Reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/google-is-not-general-reference).) Basically, if all you're doing is pointing the user to the general vicinity of where an answer could be found if sufficient diligence were applied, then you're not really answering the question.

Comment: @WithScience: I don't know. What does that article say about typecasting re: whether it applies to specific roles rather than just types of roles?

Comment: @Marthaª The article discusses what happened to Shatner, and several other famous examples.  I think it's pretty on point.  I do apologize for how brusque my original comment was.

Comment: @Marthaª: **Type casting**, and **typecasting**, are plain and unequivocal words. Your mileage may vary. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm conflicted: the OP seems determined to misunderstand my point and still hasn't actually posted any sources, just semi-snide remarks about where to find said sources, so I would dearly love to downvote this; but *typecasting* is also clearly the correct answer to this question. I think I must downvote, nonetheless.

Comment: @Marthaª, determined to be right, has become typecast as a femme fatale http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/femme%20fatale

Answer (score 3):

**Indelibly linked** is commonly used to describe this.

[Veteran Actor John Larroquette is indelibly linked with his longtime role on the series *Night Court*...](https://books.google.com/books?id=kTZsRcwe5mAC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=indelibly%20linked%20actor&source=bl&ots=UOYb8_MTUX&sig=K10wsDs5lbzsK7aZLnQTtPPuoVM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBGoVChMIjqq0i9_ixgIVhRSSCh0SIAVS#v=onepage&q=indelibly%20linked%20actor&f=false)

[But for many TV viewers Herrmann was indelibly linked to FDR...](http://www.latimes.com/local/obituaries/la-me-edward-herrmann-20150101-story.html)

And specifically talking about the Harry Potter actors:

[The "Sorcerer's Stone" film adaptation was released three years later, introducing the famous faces who would become indelibly linked with their characters.](http://stanforddailyarchive.com/cgi-bin/stanford?a=d&d=stanford20110714-01.2.29&e=07-07-1969-31-12-1970--en-20--1--txt-txIN-new%20riders------)